# Logspout send old docker logs

Tags: linux, docker, container

Hello I have logspout for sending my logs from docker container into papertrail, but now I found out 
that after restart docker container logspout send also all old logs..

Here is exaple:

```
Oct 06 15:37:09 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
Oct 06 15:37:09 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 06 15:37:09 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 06 15:37:09 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/issue_count_low.png HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 06 15:37:09 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/issue_count_high.png HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 06 15:37:09 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/issue_count_low.png HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9: 172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/issue_count_high.png HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
Oct 11 10:21:38 gridhub r-Default-gridhub-1-96bd5cd9:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and in docker container is only:

```
10/3/2017 2:38:50 PM * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
10/3/2017 2:39:05 PM172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10/3/2017 2:39:06 PM172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10/3/2017 2:39:06 PM172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/issue_count_low.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10/3/2017 2:39:06 PM172.30.100.112 - - [03/Oct/2017 12:39:06] "GET /static/issue_count_high.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10/6/2017 3:37:09 PM * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
10/11/2017 10:21:38 AM * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Do you anybody know how send only actual last logs after restart??

Comment: Ok finally I fixed it by add `BACKLOG=false` into logspout container environment..

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I fixed it by add `BACKLOG=false` into logspout container environment..
https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout#suppressing-backlog-tail